# In a connected graph, determine all nodes reachable with a "edge-simple" path from node A to node B

Tags: graphs, search-algorithms, connected

I'm asked to write an algorithm which determine all points which appear in a "edge-simple" path connecting node A and node B, i-e a path which doesn't go 2 times in the same edge, but it can go multiple times through a same node, including node A and node B.

In this simple example, with node A=0 and node B=1, all points are reachable since there exists a path 0-1-3-2-1 connecting all of them.
[image: Edge-simple path]

I wrote a piece of code in Python based on a DFS search which does work but struggles past 50 nodes. Do you have any idea of an efficient algorithm which could help me ?

Comment: Try to come up with a description of the points that cannot be in the solution, specifically check out the concept of bridges and (1-) connectivity

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i think that, if a point cannot be reached, then all path from A to B containing this point contains a bridge, but the reciprocal implication is obviously false, see my example, i might have to treat the case where the path contains a cycle apart.

Comment: If your graph has a bridge and A is on one side of it and B is on the other side, then all is good.  But if you have a bridge with A and B on the same side of it, then all the vertices on the "wrong" side of the bridge are doomed.  This means that you can look at the two-connected components that (1) contain A, (2) are between A and B, and (3) contain B.

Comment: Thank you very much, my algorithm will first look for all the bridges , then determine the bridges that are between A and B (might improve my algorithm to do both simultaneously), to determine the bridges between A and B i just need 1 path from A to B since it musts go through all the bridges between A and B. Then I remove from my graph all the nodes located on the other side of each bridge and run my DFS search on the resulting graph. I think all the remaining nodes are reachable but not sure about that